# SharePoint 2013 backup from Central Administration Errors?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server-2012

I have 2 Servers in one server I have installed SharePoint 2013 and in another server I have installed MS Sql server 2012 us back end for my SharePoint
When I want to backup my farm from Central Administration it gives the following errors:

```
Object SharePoint_Config failed in event OnBackup. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
SqlException: Cannot open backup device 'F:\SPBNew\spbr0000\00000136.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). 
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

the path it gives error is actually inside my SharePoint it is fine but I don't know why it generates like this error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem most likely involves a permissions issue and is trivial to resolve.

The account running the MSSQLSERVER service is the one that actually processes the backup.  The destination folder for the backup must be configured to specifically allow this account access.  Setting access to Everyone is insufficient.  The MSSQLSERVER service account must specifically be granted Full Control access to both the physical folder and its shared representation.  If you have configured your MSSQLSERVER service to run under the NETWORK or other domain account, simply assign Full Control permissions specifically to these accounts.

- NOTE: grant permissions to the NETWORK account.  Not the NETWORK
  SERVICE account.

If you have configured your MSSQLSERVER service to run under the System account, which is local, you will need to change the account to a domain account in order to resolve this issue.

[SharePoint 2010: Cannot open backup device 'F:[foldername]'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20732.sharepoint-2010-cannot-open-backup-device-f-foldername-operating-system-error-5-access-is-denied.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This error is occurring because your SQL server is installed on a separate server. In order to make it work you need to give path like

```
\\servername\SPBNew\spbr0000\
```

For that you should share the folder first.

Now make sure the SQL server service account has write permission on the backup folder.

http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/message.aspx?name=warning-cannot-open-backup-device